# MongoDB-JSON- How to make a query inside an array?

Tags: arrays, json, mongodb, nosql, robo3t

I have a collection with 20 documents, and each of them has an array.
i want to know how to search for an arrangement that is inside a document
it looks like:

```
"exist" : 66658,
"warehouse" : [ 
    {
        "stock_I" : "available",
        "prod_st" : "active",
        "last_sale" : "2022-11-23",
        "factura_uv" : 154368244,
        "price" : 8
    }, 
    {
        "stock_II" : "available",
        "prod_st" : "active",
        "last_sale" : "2022-04-18",
        "factura_uv" : 879624124,
        "price" : 8
    }, 
    {
        "stock_III" : "available",
        "prod_st" : "active",
        "last_sale" : "2021-07-05",
        "factura_uv" : 357846988,
        "price" : 8
    }
],
```

What i want to do is to be able to run a command that shows me only the products that are available in stock_II

my mongo version is 5.0.4

I'm grateful for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      "warehouse.stock_II": "available"
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      warehouse: {
        $filter: {
          input: "$warehouse",
          as: "w",
          cond: { $eq: [ "$$w.stock_II", "available" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/yKj7Amzn-De)

---

```
db.collection.find({
  "warehouse.stock_II": "available"
},
{
  "warehouse.$": 1
})
```

[mongoplayground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/cLYhHGbZdrW)